# Split text and build a table

Tags: r, text, split

After responding a questionnaire, I recieved the answers of it.
One of the questions was: how often do you use these languages in your work? The answers are in this format:

```
"A - Spanish 60 \r\nB - Both of them 10 \r\n C - English 30"
"B - Both of them 50 \r\n C - English 50"
"A - Spanish 30 \r\nC - English 70"
```

As you can see, each answer is formed by three different answers, preceding by `A`, `B` or `C`(Spanish, Both of them or English). Nevertheless, all three answers do not always appear, and what I would like to get is the following table:

```
Spanish | Both of them | English
   60          10           30
    0          50           50
   30           0           70
```

With `strsplit(x, "\r\n")` I separated the answers but I do not know how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me share my insights on achieving this:

```
# Pseudocode
# 1. Init: an empty matrix result,
#          #of rows equal to the number of responses
#          3 columns for Spanish, Both of them, and English.
# 2. for each response on strsplit(response, "\r\n") and extra spaces removed.
#      2.1. for each line, split it into parts using strsplit(line, " "), and
#           extract the option (A, B, or C) and the value.
#           2.1.1. Based on the option, update the corresponding cell in the result matrix.
# 3. Print the result matrix.
```

Below is the sample code:

```r
# init:
result <- matrix(0, nrow=length(responses), ncol=3)
colnames(result) <- c("Spanish", "Both of them", "English")

for (i in seq_along(responses)) {
  response <- responses[i]
  lines <- strsplit(response, "\r\n")[[1]]
  
  for (line in lines) {
    line <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", line)  # <-- Remove extra spaces
    parts <- strsplit(line, " ")[[1]]
    option <- parts[1]
    value <- as.numeric(parts[length(parts)])
    column_name <- switch(option,
                          "A" = "Spanish",
                          "B" = "Both of them",
                          "C" = "English")
    result[i, column_name] <- value
  }
}
```

*[Demo here](https://onecompiler.com/r/4238u4vxn)*

Comment: This works perfect for me  and it is completely understandable. Thank you so much @mandy8055!

Comment: You could consider `strsplit(x, r'{\s\r\n\s?}')`.

Comment: @jay.sf thanks. Actually I have kept it as separate in my answer because while devising the solution I got that problem so I mentioned in separately. We can definetely use it. Thanks again for this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
reshape(
  do.call(
    rbind,
    Map(
      \(id, x) cbind(
        rid = id,
        setNames(
          read.table(
            text = sub(".*-\\s+(\\D+)\\s+(\\d+)$", "\\1,\\2", trimws(x)),
            sep = ","
          ),
          c("lang", "score")
        )
      ),
      as.list(seq_along(s)),
      strsplit(s, split = "\r\n")
    )
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "rid",
  timevar = "lang"
)
```

which gives

```
  rid score.Spanish score.Both of them score.English
1   1            60                 10            30
4   2            NA                 50            50
6   3            30                 NA            70
```

## Data

```
s <- c(
  "A - Spanish 60 \r\nB - Both of them 10 \r\n C - English 30",
  "B - Both of them 50 \r\n C - English 50",
  "A - Spanish 30 \r\nC - English 70"
)
```